# eslint SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: reactjs, jenkins

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I have a problem when deploying in jenkins.

When I try to deploy it shows me the following error:

```
[32mInstall complete.
[39m(node:41590) [DEP0026] DeprecationWarning: util.print is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DESIGNER DEV/node_modules/eslint/lib/source-code/source-code.js:426
        return /\s/u.test(text.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//gus, ""));
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DESIGNER DEV/node_modules/eslint/lib/source-code/index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! designer-app@0.1.0 build: `fontello-cli install --config ./src/styles/components/icons/config.json --css  ./src/styles/components/icons/css --font  ./src/styles/components/icons/font && mkdir -p ./build && babel ./src/service-worker-designer.js --out-file ./build/service-worker-designer.js && react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the designer-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

From what I've been looking at it is seen that it is a problem of the [eslint](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/eslint/eslint/12493/546926382) version.

Could anyone tell me exactly what to do to fix it and be able to deploy in jenkins?

EDIT: (SOLUTION)

First, I've install svgo: [`npm install svgo@1.3.0 -E`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7901#issuecomment-547817528)

And Last, I updated jenkins node version to 8.10

Comment: dotall flag arrived on stage 4, https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case (node react app), the cause of this error is the depreciated `eslint-config-airbnb` npm module. Running `npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb` for npm 5+ works for me. Depending on the version of your npm, if your npm version is <5 then run `npm install -g install-peerdeps install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb`. Hope this help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a version of node >= 8.10?

Check this possibly related issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12493

Comment: Yes, I've tryed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my node version was too old (8.9.1). Updating node resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

this worked around the issue for me...

> In the v4.19.1, I experienced the same error from the file and line at
>   /lib/source-code/source-code.js:426
>
> The return statement of the function isSpaceBetweenTokens on the return line the following code
>   `return /\s/u.test(text.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//gus, ""));`
>   should be `return /\s/u.test(text.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//, "gus"));`
>
> This solved the problem for me but the function in the most recent src seems to be depreciated.

Source: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12538#issuecomment-552734464